# Javascript 3D Model Error

Tags: javascript, 3d, openscad, openjscad

I need support in editing a script that generates a 3D model. However I'm struggling as I keep getting errors.

```js
function handleImage(e) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(event) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      canvas.width = img.width;
      canvas.height = img.height;
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      var out = [];
      // convert image to grayscale and save in array
      for (var i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4) {
        var avg = (imgData.data[i] + imgData.data[i + 1] + imgData.data[i + 2]) / 3;
        imgData.data[i] = avg;
        imgData.data[i + 1] = avg;
        imgData.data[i + 2] = avg;
        imgData.data[i + 3] = 255;
        out.push(avg / 255);
      }
      ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
      output.value = JSON.stringify(out);
    }
    img.src = event.target.result;
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

```html
<label>Image File:</label>
<br/>
<input type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader" />
<canvas id="imageCanvas"></canvas>
<textarea rows="10" cols="100" id="output"></textarea>
```

[JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/threonin/6dr8qu41/)

The code is supposed to create a 3D file similar to the images found in [this link](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:294899). The image I want is the below to be on a 3D model using OpenJSCAD or OpenSCAD software.

[image]

Comment: The code you have doesn't generate a 3d image. It converts a colour image to a grayscale one.

Comment: What changes would I need to implement, to make to able to generate a 3D image ?

Comment: Just add in the code to do what you want. All it does currently is uploads a graphics file and removes the colour. It does nothing else.